# R Shiny - dynamically created actionButtons either all firing at once (observeEvent) or not firing at all (eventReactive)

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I am building a Shiny app and modeling a portion of it off this article: [https://antoineguillot.wordpress.com/2017/03/01/three-r-shiny-tricks-to-make-your-shiny-app-shines-33-buttons-to-delete-edit-and-compare-datatable-rows/]...

I am dynamically creating actionButtons within the row names of a datatable (that is created after user inputs and outputted to a new tab once 'Run' is clicked). When these actionButtons are clicked, I want a modal to pop up to give more detailed information for that row. I was able to create the buttons based on the code in the article above, however I'm having trouble getting them to fire properly...

I started by creating an observeEvent for every button. However, they all fire when the table is created (instead of waiting for the button to be clicked), and only the last row's modal is active afterwards. Then none of the buttons worked after dismissing that modal. When I tried eventReactive instead of observeEvent, they never fired at all, even when clicked.

Here is a simple version of what I am attempting:

```
ui<-navbarPage(title="Title", theme=shinytheme("cosmo"), id="navbar",
           tabPanel("Main",
                    selectInput(inputId="rows", label="# of Rows", choices=c(5,10,25)),
                    actionButton(inputId="run", "Run"))
           )

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    iris_data<-iris[1:input$rows,]
    row.names(iris_data)<-paste0("<button id='details_", 1:nrow(iris_data),"' type='button' class='btn btn-default action-button shiny-bound-input'", ">Details</button>")
    output$iris<-renderDT({
      datatable(iris_data, selection="single", escape=FALSE,
      )
    })
    for (i in 1:nrow(iris_data)) {
      eventReactive(paste0("input$details_",i), {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(h3(strong("Details"), align="center")), hr(),
              fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Sepal Length: "), iris_data[i,1])),
              fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Sepal Width: "), iris_data[i,2])),
              fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Petal Length: "), iris_data[i,3])),
              fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Petal Width: "), iris_data[i,4])),
              fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Species: "), iris_data[i,5])),
          size="l"))
        )}
      )}
    appendTab(inputId="navbar", tabPanel("Data", dataTableOutput("iris")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

What can I change in the code above to make sure these buttons fire if (and only if) they are clicked? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with `input[[paste0("details_",i)]]` ? I can't try because you provide only a piece of the code. You should provide a complete minimal reproducible example to get valuable help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Stephane. I changed the code in my post to be a complete minimal reproducible example using the generic data-set iris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with the code below.

- the `drawCallback` option runs `Shiny.bindAll` on the table; it tells Shiny that new inputs are added
- the use of `local` in the for loop is needed, otherwise the value of `i` would be the same across all instances in the loop (it would be the last `i`)

---

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    iris_data <- iris[1:input$rows,]
    row.names(iris_data) <- paste0("<button id='details_", 1:nrow(iris_data),"' type='button' class='btn btn-default action-button'", ">Details</button>")
    output$iris <- renderDT({
      datatable(iris_data, selection="single", escape=FALSE, 
                options = list(
                  drawCallback = JS(
                    "function(){",
                    "  Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());",
                    "}"
                  )
                )
      )
    })
    appendTab(inputId="navbar", tabPanel("Data", DTOutput("iris")))
  })

  observeEvent(input$rows, {
    for(j in 1:input$rows){
      local({
        i <- j
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("details_",i)]], {
          showModal(
            modalDialog(
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(h3(strong("Details"), align="center")), hr(),
                fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Sepal Length: "), iris[i,1])),
                fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Sepal Width: "), iris[i,2])),
                fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Petal Length: "), iris[i,3])),
                fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Petal Width: "), iris[i,4])),
                fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Species: "), iris[i,5])),
                size="l"))
          )
        })
      })
    }
  })

}
```

---

Here is an alternative way:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)

ui<-navbarPage(
  title="Title", id="navbar",
  tabPanel("Main",
           selectInput(inputId="rows", label="# of Rows", choices=c(5,10,25)),
           actionButton(inputId="run", "Run")),
  tabPanel("Data", 
           DTOutput("iris"),
           uiOutput("modals"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$iris <- renderDT({
    if(input$run > 0){
      iris_data <- iris[1:input$rows,]
      row.names(iris_data) <- sapply(1:input$rows, function(i){
        paste0("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default action-button'",
               " onclick = \"", sprintf("$('#modal%d').modal('show');\"", i),
               ">Details</button>")
      }) 
      datatable(iris_data, selection="single", escape=FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$modals <- renderUI({
    modals <- lapply(1:input$rows, function(i){
      bsModal(
        id = paste0("modal",i), 
        title = paste0("Details of row ", i),
        trigger = "",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Sepal Length: "), iris[i,1])),
          fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Sepal Width: "), iris[i,2])),
          fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Petal Length: "), iris[i,3])),
          fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Petal Width: "), iris[i,4])),
          fluidRow(splitLayout(strong("Species: "), iris[i,5]))
        )
      )
    })
    do.call(tagList, modals)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: @SeanSlavin This works but the app is a bit messy. There's an issue when one goes back to the Main tab and runs again.

Comment: Thank you Stephane! I was able to get this to work on my app... I have a plan to get this to work when going back to the Main tab and running again. I have a 'Name Query' input in the real app that names the new tab & table. I need to be able to account for if a user inputs the same name twice (I'm planning to add a " (2)" to the end of their name input).

I just need to apply that same logic to the ids of the actionButtons. It may be tricky, but I think I can get it to work.

Comment: @SeanSlavin I've just edited my answer to add an alternative way.